# How to add a custom action function using Django DRF viewset.Viewsets?

Tags: django, django-rest-viewsets

I have a viewset that I created an @action decorated function.

```
class StoreOffersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """Viewset for yoga stuff."""

    @action(detail=False, methods=['put'], name='yoga update')
        def update_yoga(self, request):
            # Get Kwargs passed
            params = self.kwargs
```

In my urls, I have:

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=True)
router.register(r'yoga', views.StoreOffersViewSet, basename='yoga')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I would like that when a user has a PUT request to site.com/yoga, my update_yoga function is called.

As it stands now, I get the following error:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"PUT\" not allowed."
}
```

My guess is that this is because for the default router, GET and POST already have the url style from the docs, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter. So I am not too sure how to proceed. I am on django 3.8>

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem you are facing may be in the URL you are calling. For performing the action you mentioned above you will need to use this URL,
"/yoga/<int:pk>/update_yoga"

If you want that your put request should call update_yoga, then you can override the default put function.

for example,

```
class YogaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    querset = Yoga.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YogaSerializers
    
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```